# Download ZipArchive OutOfMemory

Tags: php, symfony, download, out-of-memory, symfony4

I've an issue when downloading a file on my heroku app.
I've a basic PHP ini which allows us to have 128MB, for memory limit.

My Error is as follows:

> (1/1) OutOfMemoryException Error: Allowed memory size of 134217728
> bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 77709312 bytes)

Ok I got it, but the weird thing is `77709312bytes` are only 74MB.

So what's wrong?

This a the code of my download action:

```
/**
 * @Route("/templates/{id}/download", name="api_templates_download", requirements={"id"="\d+"})
 * @Method({"GET"})
 * @param \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request $request
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 * @throws \Exception
 */
public function downloadTemplate(Request $request)
{
    $id = $request->get('id');

    try {
        $template = $this->service->getTemplate($id, $this->helper->getUser());
        $archive = $this->service->downloadTemplate($template);
        $response = new Response(file_get_contents($archive));
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/zip');
        $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment;filename="' . $archive . '"');
        $response->headers->set('Content-length', filesize($archive));

        return $response;
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $response = new Response(json_encode($e->getMessage()), 401);
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        return $response;
    }
}
```

And the method `downloadTemplate` called in the controller:

```
/**
 * @tests Need to tests about performance - do this in September with real server
 * @param \App\Domain\Dollycast\Template\Entity\Template $template
 * @return string
 */
public function downloadTemplate(Template $template)
{
    $zip = new \ZipArchive();
    $zipName = self::ZIPDIR . $template->getName() . '.zip';

    $zip->open($zipName, \ZipArchive::CREATE);

    $finder = new Finder();
    $finder->files()->in(self::WORKDIR . $template->getName());

    $zip->addEmptyDir($template->getName());
    /** @var SplFileInfo $file */
    foreach ($finder as $file) {
        // Rename the full path to the relative Path
        $zip->addFile(
            self::WORKDIR . $template->getName() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file->getRelativePathname(),
            $template->getName() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file->getRelativePathname()
        );
    }

    $zip->close();

    return $zipName;
}
```

Comment: I'll also suggest to use file_get_contents($archive) in your logic side :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`file_get_contents` will load the file into memory, when I put this into the `Response` object, this will effectively copy all the content from memory to the output buffer. This is why an archive wich is around `74MB` will result in `Out of memory` for 128M configuration (74*2) error due to double work.

At this time, I can't use `readfile()` to solve this problem because the behaviour is too much different for my needs. But `readfile()` will open and output into buffer without using twice memory.

EDIT : The best alternative I found is by using the `BinaryFileResponse` object from Symfony 3.2 wich handle effectively the response stream.

Answer (score 1):

> (1/1) OutOfMemoryException Error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 77709312 bytes)

At the time, the php proccess tries to allocate 77709312 bytes it already has memory allocated, which can be checked with the function memory_get_usage(). In your case, this must be more than (134217728 - 77709312 =) 56508416 bytes.

If the exception is raised during the creation of the zip file, you can try to use an external tool to create the zip file. Something like

> exec("tar -zcvf archive.tar.gz /folder/tozip");

Otherwise try to find out when exactly this exception is thrown an try to free all unnecessary used memory.

Comment: Don't think so, because my archive is indead around 77709312 MB. Plus the error message don't say about additionnal bytes, but total bytes.

Comment: The process tries to allocate 77709312 bytes, but this is not possible because then it would exceed the maximum of 134217728 bytes, because at this moment your application allready uses more than (134217728 - 77709312 =) 56508416 bytes.

Comment: Do you know in which line the error occures? While creating the zip or at "file_get_contents($archive)"?

Answer (score -1):

Did you try `file_get_contents($zipName); unlink($zipName);` so you can delete file from local

Comment: Hi, thanks but it's not relevant to my issue, take a look at my answer :p

Comment: I know i just wanted to point out the unlink to avoid storing big zip file :)